# Can the word 'just so' be a substitute for the word 'so that'?

Tags: grammar

Earlier today, I was watching a CSS tutorial on Youtube. I noticed the author use the sentence
'just remove the margins and padding  ***just so*** we can see everything clearly. This wasn't the first time I noticed a native speaker use the word 'just so'. I noticed a lot of native speakers on Youtube use the word ***just so***. Can that be a substitute for the word ***so that***?

Comment: 'just' can also mean 'exactly'. Just like that = exactly like that; just in time = exactly in time. ('Just' has other meanings too.) That way, 'just so' can mean 'exactly so'. In this example, 'so that' can replace 'just so'.

Comment: That's not how it works. "...remove the margins and padding so (that) we can see everything clearly" is the _basic_ expression. The subordinator "that" is optional and the adverb "just" can also be optionally added.

Comment: _just so_ is actually a _set phrase_ (of sorts) implying a neat and careful arrangement of things. As in _The books are arranged just so._ And I think @BillJ has nailed it logically as to why it makes for an untenable choice over the chaste _so that._

Comment: By the way, if I choose to omit _that_ from the sentence (_Conjunction Reduction_), and say simply—  **Just remove the margins and padding, so we can see everything clearly,** am I not risking running into the _comma splice_ error? The problem occurs even if _that_ is retained, right? How should one render the sentence better then? @BillJ?

Comment: @User40475  No problem with or without "that". "So" tells us that the clause that follows it is subordinate. And you don't need the comma either.